# Airflow with oracle backend

Tags: oracle, airflow

In my company we are evaluating the use of Airflow mainly to run ML model.

In the documentation they suggest to use Postgres or MySQL, but we prefer to stick with our tools, in this particular scenario we'd like to give to Airflow a dedicated schema in Oracle Database Enteprise Edition 19.

Is it possible to have oracle as a backend db? Are there any drawback?

Comment: Metadata is not oracle as far as i know. it's postgre, sqlite or Mysql.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that Oracle is not supported as a backend for Airflow corresponding to the Jira ticket: [AIRFLOW-3994](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-commits/201904.mbox/%3CJIRA.13219054.1551499589000.123057.1556020680167@Atlassian.JIRA%3E)

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/oracle.html), it seems that you can use Oracle with airflow.

Comment: Already seen it. But it seems that this is referencing to the connection to query data for the application. It's different from setting a backend db for Airflow metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow can run with any DB supported by SqlAlchemy. For example:

- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- SQLite
- Oracle
- Microsoft SQL Server

List of supported dialects: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/

Although from my experience I recommend using Postgres from my experience and for performance reasons.